# How to retrieve data from json file in angular 7

Tags: json, angular, http, frontend, crud

This is my `doma.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-doma',
  templateUrl: './doma.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doma.component.css']
})
export class DomaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  auti=[];
  dohvatiPodatke=function(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:9999/auti").subscribe(
      (res:Response) => {
        this.auti=res.json();
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dohvatiPodatke();
  }

}
```

my `doma.component.html`:

```
<h1>Auti</h1>

<table>
    <th>Marka</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Cijena</th>

    <tr *ngFor="let auto of auti">
        <td>{{auti.marka}}</td>
        <td>{{auti.model}}</td>
        <td>{{auti.cijena}}</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my json file:

```
{
    "auti":[
        {
            "marka": "Mercedes",
            "model": "AMG",
            "cijena": "200000"
        },
        {
            "marka": "Seat",
            "model": "Leon",
            "cijena": "150000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I successfully compiled and ran the project but i only get the table structure with no data in it. Before that i started the json server on my 9999 port and i can access it via `localhost/9999/auti`. I really don' see what could be the problem here.

Comment: `this.auti=res.json();` no needt to convert to json simply use  `this.auti=res;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```js
this.http.get("http://localhost:9999/auti").subscribe(res => this.auti = res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop over the parent object instead of the child array. Replace `this.auti=res.json();` with `this.auti=res.json().auti;`. So the HTTP callback would look like

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:9999/auti").subscribe(
  (res:Response) => {
    this.auti=res.json().auti;
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep your json into assets folder

Use relative path to read it:

```
auti=[];
  dohvatiPodatke=function(){
    this.http.get("./assests/auti-jsonfile.json").subscribe(
      (res:Response) => {
        this.auti=res;
      }
    )
  }
```